# How to set a parameter ID,1234 in a HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, servlets, interceptor, servlet-filters

I have a HttpServletrequest which contains some parameter.
I want to add this key and value into that request.
How can I intercept it with my code and add that into my request?
I have created a filter like following but not really able to proceed

```
public class RequestInterceptor implements Filter {        
    public RequestInterceptor() {        
    }

     
    public void destroy() {
         
    }

     
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

     
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
         
    }
```

I want to do like request.setAttribute("ID", "1234")
So this will be appended or added into my request

In general I want to modify the httpServletRequest with the help of interceptor or filter

Comment: Your question could use more detail since it's not clear exactly what you are trying to do.  Could it be you're looking for `request.getParameter("ID")` or `request.setAttribute("ID", "1234")` ?

Comment: @delux247 I want to request.setAttribute("ID", "1234")

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that you could do something like this:

**Using web.xml**

```java
import java.io.IOException; 
import javax.servlet.Filter; 
import javax.servlet.FilterChain; 
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig; 
import javax.servlet.ServletException; 
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest; 
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class IdMutatorFilter implements Filter {

    public IdMutatorFilter() {
        // Nothing to construct
    }
    
    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Nothing to do here =/
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Your preferred method to make an object number here.
        request.setAttribute("ID", Integer.parseInt("1234"));
        // Then return they.
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // Nothing to do here
    }


}
```

Your filter will change the attribute inside the request and pass it forward by calling the `chain.doFilter` method.

And in your `web.xml` file you should add at your root something like this:

```xml
<filter> 
    <filter-name>YourFilterName</filter-name> 
    <filter-class>com.package.location.YourFilterName</filter-class> 
</filter>
 <filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>YourFilterName</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

The `filter` tag register your filter, giving it a name and point to the class that implements it.

The `filter-mapping` register url patterns in witch the filter need to be applied.

Where `url-pattern` is the pattern in witch your filter will be applied and `filter-class` is the fqn of your class.

**Using annotations**

Using this approach you do not need to register the filter with the `web.xml` file, but your Servlet API version need to be at least 3.0.

You can see the [docs here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html)

```java
 import java.io.IOException; 
import javax.servlet.Filter; 
import javax.servlet.FilterChain; 
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig; 
import javax.servlet.ServletException; 
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest; 
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest; 
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebInitParam;

@WebFilter(filterName = "YourFilterName",
urlPatterns = {"/*"})
public class IdMutatorFilter implements Filter {

    public IdMutatorFilter() {
        // Nothing to construct
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // Nothing to do here =/
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Your preferred method to make an object number here.
        request.setAttribute("ID", Integer.parseInt("1234"));
        // Then return they.
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        // Nothing to do here
    }


}
```

Comment: You can also use annotations if you don't want to use `web.xml`.

Comment: I tried the same
public class RequestInterceptor implements Filter {
 public RequestInterceptor() {
    }public void destroy() {
 }
     public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
  long UID=System.currentTimeMillis();
        request.setAttribute("ID", UID);
        
  chain.doFilter(request, response);
 }

 public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 }

}


But didn't worked

Comment: @stdunbar I've added a annotation version of the filter class.

Comment: @akshaykale you have to make sure that the Filter is correctly registered, and that the URL that you are testing is indeed being filtered using the URL pattern used by the filter, if the filter isn't registered or the URL requested isn't being contemplated by the URL pattern the filter will not be used for that request.

Comment: @ooredroxoo  
I tried the same but it is still not adding into the request

Comment: @akshaykale, hmmm, this is strange, if you can could you try to debug your code to see if the ```doFilter``` is called? If it is then the problem is probably inside the ```doFilter``` method and we should fix it, if it isn't then there is a problem with the way the filter was registered, in a way that it isn't being called when the server process the request.

Comment: @ooredroxoo Please check below I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

/**
 * Servlet Filter implementation class RequestInterceptor
 */
@WebFilter("/RequestInterceptor")
public class RequestInterceptor implements Filter  {

    
    
    
    public RequestInterceptor() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        RequestInterceptionforIDWrappper wrapper =new RequestInterceptionforIDWrappper((HttpServletRequest) request);
        long ID=85965894;
        wrapper.setUniqueID("UID",ID);
        chain.doFilter(wrapper, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
     */
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }



}
```

============================

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

public class RequestInterceptionforIDWrappper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    HashMap UIDkeyValue=new HashMap<>();
    public RequestInterceptionforIDWrappper(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);      
    }
    
    public void setUniqueID(String UID,long ID) {
        
        UIDkeyValue.put(UID, ID);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getParameter(String key) {
        return UIDkeyValue.toString();
    }

}
```

This are two of the classes I have Tried to add key value into request can you check what's wrong
@ooredroxoo